# Are these particular vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have worked out that they are linearly independent but the mark scheme says there are not. Please help my exam is tomorrow.

vectors are: $(1, 2, 3, 4)^T$ , $(2, 5, 8, 11)^T$, $(1, 0, -1, -1)^T$

Comment: What definition of "linearly independent" are you working with?

Comment: Only all zero scalars lets the linear combination of them equal zero

Comment: They are linearly independent according to WolframAlpha

Comment: The mark scheme is wrong. The likeliest reasons are that you misread the question or that there’s a typo in it.

Answer (score 1):

$-5$ times the first, plus $2$ times the second, plus $1$ times the third gives the zero-vector.

[Except, as the comments point out, I miscomputed the fourth entry].

Hence they are dependent.

How did I work that out? Well, I could have written out 
$$
a \pmatrix{1\\2\\3\\4} + b \pmatrix{2\\5\\8\\11} + c \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ -1} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0},
$$
which then becomes four equations in three unknowns, and found a solution. In practice, I said "no matter what $c$ is, if I know $b$, then I can figure out $a$ from the second equation, $2a + 5b = 0$. For instance, if $b = 1$, then $a = -2.5$. I can make that simpler by taking $b = 2$ and $a = -5$. So let's see where that leads." I computed
$$
-5 \pmatrix{1\\2\\3\\4} + 2 \pmatrix{2\\5\\8\\11} =  \pmatrix{-1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1}
$$
and [mistakenly] realized that this was just the negative of the third vector, and I was done.

In fact, any combination of the first two vectors that has a $0$ in the second component is a multiple of $\pmatrix{-1\\0\\1\\2}$, so that adding a multiple of the third vector to it cannot yield zero. Thus the three vectors are in fact independent.

My conjecture is that the last entry of the third vector was meant to be $-2$ rather than $-1$.

To prove **independence**, you can look at the equations associated to the first, second, and fourth rows, namely
\begin{align}
a + 2b + c &= 0 \\
2a + 5b  &= 0 \\
4a + 11b -c   &= 0 \\
\end{align}
Doubling the first and subtracting from the second, and quadrupling the first and subtracting from the third leads to 
\begin{align}
a + 2b + c &= 0 \\
  b  &= 0 \\
 + 3b - 5c   &= 0 \\
\end{align}

From $b = 0$, substituting in the third shows $c = 0$, and then the first shows $a = 0$. Hence any linear combination that's zero must have all coefficients be zero, and the vectors are independent.

Comment: the last coordinate is not 0.

Comment: D'oh! I took $22 - 20$ and said "ah...that's 1". I'm an idiot. :(

Comment: See addenda, and corrected answer, including a proof that the vectors are indeed independent, and the answer key is wrong.